# Android alert dialog not shown

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I create and show an alert dialog from onPostResume method of the Activity.
The dialog is not shown but i cannot understand why.

My code for showing the dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("message");
builder.setPositiveButton("a", aListener);
builder.setPositiveButton("b", bListener);
builder.setCancelable(false);

AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
dlg.show();
```

Comment: include your code, otherwise it's impossible to know what's wrong

Comment: That code seems ok... Are you positive your code is running? Try adding a log message. Also, what does your `onPostResume()` method signature look like?

Comment: try one line at a time `builder.setPositiveButton("a", aListener);
builder.setPositiveButton("b", bListener);` from these..may be something wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("message");
builder.setPositiveButton("a", aListener);
builder.setPositiveButton("b", bListener);
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.show();
```

**Note:** There is no reason to create another `AlertDialog` instance.

---

Or another correct approach you can create method that returns new `AlertDialog`:

```
protected static final int CREATE_INFORMATION_DIALOG = 1320;

private Dialog createDialog(int type) {
        AlertDialog dialog = null;
        switch (type) {
            case CREATE_INFORMATION_DIALOG:
                dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Information")
                    .setMessage("Download was finished successfully.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int whichButton) {

                        }
                    })
                    .create();
                break;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

And then just call it like

```
createDialog(CREATE_INFORMATION_DIALOG).show();
```

Comment: try to use onResume method instead of onPostResume

Comment: so problem is elsewhere. did you try it with method as i meant?